# Unable to launch android applications in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having a weird problem with Eclipse.

Some days back, I completed a project with the name `IntelligentAlarm`, and then pushed it to github. I was using Eclipse Indigo then. After that I formatted the system, and downloaded Eclipse Juno. I cloned this repository from github, and imported this project into Eclipse as an android application.

But now, I am unable to run it as an android application. The option which allows you to run it as an android application is missing. Neither can I create a new Run Configuration for this project, as I don't see this project in Browse window.

I should add that I am able to run newly created android projects.

What should I do ?

Comment: If you are intending to develop mostly for Android [I recommend using the ADT bundle](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) instead of standalone versions of eclipse. It comes pre-packeged with the SDK and is already configured for Android development. As for your project you probably just need to delete some of the eclipse generate files and then import it as an Android Application into your IDE. Without seeing your project I couldn't say for sure though.

Comment: I deleted and re-imported the project at least 3-4 times. But the problem is not solved.

Comment: I meant delete the eclipse generated config files like `.project` and `project.properties` and the `.settings\` folder. In general you'll want to add those to gitignore for Android projects. But again, without being able to see your project I can only make guesses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you formatted your hard disk your workspace is gone. This means you have to import your cloned project into Eclipse (*Import existing Android project into workspace*). This adds your project to the newly created workspace. After that, if will be shown in your IDE as usual.

It might be that you have still some things to do, for instance downloading the SDK platforms and creating an emulator.

After this you should be able to run your program as an Android project.

Comment: I did that. Cloned the repository, and imported as android project. There was no problem while importing, but now I cannot run that particular application. Other apps I created after that run perfectly.

Comment: Did everything compile well? Check the `Problems` view in Eclipse. In addition: double check that the SDK Plugin is installed and the path to Android is set in the preferences

Comment: Yeah, everything is perfect. There are no problems in that project, everything complied without any error. And I am able to run the other applications. There is no problem with the SDK Plugin.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but the emulator(s) in my IDE are not updating time on real-time basis. The clock is stuck at the time I started the emulator. I tried changing the settings, but nothings works.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions in your project? May be the `bin` folder can't be written or something else. I had once some issues with file permissions when I put the SDK in `Program files`. Just a guess ...

Comment: Maybe that's the case. But I guess it has got something to do with the IDE. My other app is using an AlarManager, and the alarm fires instantly though I have checked and rechecked that the time at which it is supposed to fire is not equal to 0. Currently I am downloading the ADT Bundle. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-do the android app setup configuration in Eclipse again and see if the

> Run > As an Android App

option comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Eclipse form scratch to enable Android Development Environment. [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Then create new project from your existing code. Since you exisitng eclipse project will have the properly files it will enable any old properties.

Hope you have your old workspace.

**Quick Solution:** **You can try deleting the .metadata folder under workspace folder which can recreate the .metadata folder for you when restart the eclipse**